# change database from command prompt

Tags: canalyzer

I am able to launch canalyzer from command prompt by a simple
`>CANw64.exe`

I am also able to load a configuration with
`>CANw64.exe config_file.cfg`

but I can't find if it is possible to change the database from prompt, I tried
`>CANw64.exe config_file.cfg database.dbc`

but it does not work. I got the error message:
`The specified file contains an invalid configuration`

would you know how I can resolve this?

Comment: I do not know such command, maybe Vector does. But I would try to simply modify in text format the CANalyzer configuration which practically contains the linked databases. There must be a path with the linked databases, as CANoe cfgs have.

Comment: there is the path to linked databases in cfg file, but I have tried to configure "normally" (using canalyzer) the database. I then compared cfg with database1 and cfg with database2 and other things changed in the file, not only the lines with link to database. So I find it risky to only modify these lines

Comment: Also, there is not "the" database. You can have multiple databases (by bus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got the answer from the Vector support, this is not possible to do it from command prompt. The only way to automate this is to use a Vector COM server